# Determining level of significance when hypothesis is an interval

Tags: probability, statistics

For a normally distributed sample:

σ = 60

Sample size = n = 12

Sample mean = x = 3450

Null Hypothesis = H_o ≠ 3500

Hypothesis = H_1 = 3500

I need to determine the smallest significance level at which I can reject the null hypothesis, α

Based on the formula I have,

α = P(Reject H_o | H_o is true)

I set my interval of Ho rejection to,

(3498.5,3501.5)

Then:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2bLY.png

I'm pretty certain my method is wrong, anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch null and alternative hypotheses.
No need for rejection interval. Compute two-tailed p-value  = 0.0039 .
If $p<\alpha$ we Reject null and do not reject otherwise.
So $\alpha =0.0039$ is the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in setting up the interval. First of all the interval is for $H_0$ *acceptance*. Since $H_0$ is that $\mu=3500$, when you have a sample mean *close* to that predicted by $H_0$, you accept $H_0$.

Anyway, to find the minimal value of $\alpha$, you want to choose your interval so that the observed sample mean is right on the edge between the acceptance region and the rejection region. That is, you want to choose the interval $(3450,3550)$. Then $\alpha$ is the probability of falling *outside* this interval, given the distribution of the sample mean predicted by $H_0$, i.e. $N(3500,60/\sqrt{12})$. In particular we have

$$\alpha = 1 - P ( 3450 < \bar{X} < 3550 ) = 1 - P ( -50 \sqrt{12}/60 < Z < 50 \sqrt{12}/60 ) = \dots$$

Comment: Why did you state, "Since H0 is that μ=3500", when H_o ≠ 3500?

Comment: Because you also named your hypotheses incorrectly. For basic statistics purposes, $H_0$ is always an equality. It has to be, because when you perform hypothesis testing, you *assume* $H_0$ and then perform probability calculations using that assumption.